how do we send bell notification for incoming emails on Cases
I have a requirement where I need to send custom bell notification in Salesforce when Case owner is changed or customer send any email on the case. I am able to send custom notification on owner change using flows and  custom notifications. How can I do this for incoming emails?

Refer to this: https://www.salesforceben.com/set-up-salesforce-push-notifications/

You should be able to do this using flows and custom notifications as well. You can use a record-triggered flow (after save) on the object "Email Message" where the field Incoming is true (to avoid notifications on any outgoing emails). You might need to add additional entry conditions to fit your particular implementation, but this is the general idea.

